# UITableView cells disappearing, wrong cell passed to didEndDisplayingCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I'm seeing another case of UITableView cells disappearing unexpectedly when scrolling, but none of the similar questions & answers here I've seen really fit what I'm seeing:

I scroll down until my top cell is removed and `tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` is called for it, then scroll back up until it's shown again. During the scroll up, the tableview is trying to remove the cells that were shown while scrolling down, however its actually removing the wrong cells.

As I'm scrolling up, `tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` is getting called with the correct index path, one it should be removing, but a cell that corresponds to a different index path. The cell and index path passed to the `didEndDisplayingCell` don't match.

This is in a small modification of the XLForm example project from https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLForm in which I've added a custom cell. What's weird is that if I make my custom cell the same height as the table's normal height (44) then this doesn't happen. Only when my cell is taller (64, with this value returned from `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` and `tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:`).

I'm seeing this happen when running in the simulator, iOS versions 8.4 and 9.2.

I haven't been able to figure this out. I don't think I have any of the bugs that have caused others to have disappearing cell syndrome, but even if I do, I don't see how or why the tableview would be calling `didEndDisplayingCell` with cell and index path that don't match. Does anyone else have a clue what's happening?

Comment: If you have found a bug in the simulator or on a device (and especially if you have example code) then please report it to Apple: https://bugreport.apple.com . Having said that, do you have a small MCVE you can add to your question that demonstrates this problem?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. The indexpath passed by iOS and the cell do not match.

Comment: Also having the same bug - Did you find a solution, or file a bug report?

Comment: no, didn't find a solution. finished work with that client and i haven't run into this problem since. curious, anyone else having this problem, is it also when using xlform or no? i would have submitted a bug report if i could find a reproducible case without that dependency.